# Azure share devtest lab base between different labs

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-devtest-labs

I have several devtest labs in different resource groups in Azure. I want to be able to use a base image created in one in the other.

I see that other base images are saved as snapshot objects.

[image]

I have exported the base that I want as a snapshot, but I can't seem to get it into my devtest lab. When I click add a custom image I only get the option to Upload a VHD from my computer, or use an existing VHD. But I cannot find my snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried in my environment to select the custom image from snapshot.

I have created one **DevTest lab** and added virtual machine to the DevTest lab like below.

[image]

I have created ***snapshot*** of particular virtual machine like below:

[image]

[image]

I have selected the snapshot has a custom image while creating the New Virtual Machine instead of Gallery Image like below.

[image]

Alternatively, I have created Mutiple DevTest lab with different resource groups as you mentioned. Unfortunately, it's not supported with different resources like below.

[image]

***Reference***:

[Create a custom image from a lab VM - Azure DevTest Labs | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-create-custom-image-from-vm-using-portal)

[Create and add a virtual machine to a lab - Azure DevTest Labs | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devtest-labs/devtest-lab-add-vm)